# wine on lubuntu

Tags: wine, playonlinux, winetricks

Can anyone send me a proper link to install and use wine on Lubuntu 22.04? I would prefer to install from synaptic or from a debina file, than terminal.
There are so many ways to do it, and nothing works yet.
I dont think it is the same to install on Ubuntu.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your issue?  A simple `sudo apt install winetricks` will install https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/winetricks    That will install the same package as Ubuntu 22.04 installs, as both are Ubuntu systems using the same repositories.

Comment: Lubuntu uses a LXQt desktop, thus using `synaptic` (a GTK3 app) would be inefficient, thus why it includes [Muon Package Manager](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/4/4.2/muon.html) as well as Discover.  I'd expect to see `winetricks` listed there too, but sorry I've not checked as I'm not running *jammy* (22.04) currently.

Answer (score 1):

A simple

`sudo apt install winetricks`

will install https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/winetricks

or to install `wine` itself it's just

`sudo apt install wine`

which will install https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/wine

That will install the same package(s) as Ubuntu 22.04 installs, as both are Ubuntu systems using the same repositories.

Lubuntu is a *community* distribution of Ubuntu, thus comes by default with 'universe' enabled, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop does not and requires 'universe' to be enabled, but both Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Lubuntu 22.04 LTS use the identical package from the same repository.

For more details on repositories, please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: FYI:  I'm involved with the Lubuntu team, and as such am a Ubuntu member. Lubuntu is *official* Ubuntu and thus can only use packages found in Ubuntu repositories, we just use a different [seed](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/lubuntu.jammy/desktop) which causes our ISO to include different packages, but all packages are from the same repositories as all Ubuntu systems are. Commands are thus the same with regards packaging.

Comment: Sorry, my wording on 'involved' with Lubuntu team & subsequently Ubuntu member was unfortunate..   A Lubuntu member will become a Ubuntu member, but not all involved with the Lubuntu team reach member status until after "*significant and sustained*" contributions are reached & thus membership attained by application.  Personally I was Ubuntu member prior to becoming involved with Lubuntu & gaining Lubuntu member status, but if I'd not already a Ubuntu member, I would have become one then. My attempted point is Lubuntu & Ubuntu are both Ubuntu systems. I refer to my Lubuntu box as a Ubuntu box.